# How i can get the Client IP Address in GWAN Server Using Java?

Tags: java, ip-address, g-wan

Well, the title says everything:

How I can get the Client IP Address in GWAN Server Using Java?

I saw that in C there is a way, but in Java I could not find anything yet. Are not all the methods implemented in Java to interact with GWAN?

Comment: You can't. The **ONLY** IP address a webserver can reliably retrieve is the IP from where the client's connection was opened from. If the user is behind a nat gateway or proxy or vpn, that'll be the ip of the gateway/proxy/vpn, **NOT** the client's actual IP. You cannot get the client machine's actual IPs without running code directly on the client.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, you are right, that is the IP that i need, the Public Client IP Address, is possible with a GWAN Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

The `Gwan.java` class that implements the G-WAN Java API starts with the following comments:

```
// ============================================================================
// Java API calls for the G-WAN Web App. Server (http://trustleap.ch/)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Compile with: javac Gwan.java
// 
// The G-WAN API getStrEnv() Java function returns a Java string for:
//
//   REQUEST             +
//   QUERY_STRING        |
//   FRAGMENT_ID         |
//   REQ_ENTITY          |
//   VHOST_ROOT          |
//   WWW_ROOT            |
//   CSP_ROOT            |
//   LOG_ROOT            | a copy of the G-WAN C string
//   HLD_ROOT            | 
//   FNT_ROOT            |
//   REMOTE_ADDR         |
//   USER_AGENT          |
//   SERVER_SOFTWARE     |
//   SERVER_NAME         |
//   SERVER_ADDR         |
//   SERVER_DATE         +
//
// Use getIntEnv() for the many integer values (like REQUEST_LEN)
//
// ...but these get_env() values are ignored by Java getxxxEnv() calls:
//
//   HTTP_CODE           +
//   SCRIPT_TMO          |
//   KALIVE_TMO          |
//   REQUEST_TMO         | 
//   DOWNLOAD_SPEED      | pointers on integers
//   MIN_READ_SPEED      |
//   MAX_ENTITY_SIZE     |
//   US_HANDLER_STATES   +
//
//   US_HANDLER_DATA     +
//   US_VHOST_DATA       | pointers on user-defined data structures
//   US_SERVER_DATA      +
//
//   READ_XBUF           + pointers on G-WAN internal structures
//   HTTP_HEADERS        +
//
// If you want to contribute in this matter (by helping to implement Java 
// G-WAN API in C with JNI), then drop us a line, you are most welcome!
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, yes, you can use `Gwan.getIntEnv()` with the value `REMOTE_ADDR` to access the client IP address seen by the G-WAN server.

Comment: Hello @Gil for your reply, maybe that code is in other Version?

this is what i see in the lasted Gwan version available in the Web page: 

**Gwan.java:**
`
// ============================================================================
// Java API calls for the G-WAN Web App. Server (http://trustleap.ch/)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
package api;

public class Gwan 
{
   public static native long getReply(long env);
 ...
`

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Gil for your reply,

maybe that code is in other Version? this is what i see in the lasted Gwan version available in the Web page:

Gwan.java:

```
// ============================================================================ 
// Java API calls for the G-WAN Web App. Server (trustleap.ch) 
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
package api; 
public class Gwan { 
public static native long getReply(long env); 
    public static native void xbufCat (long ctx, String str);
    public static native long cycles64();
    public static native long getNs   ();
    public static native long getUs   ();
    public static native long getMs   ();
    public static native void logErr  (long env, String msg);
    public static native void report  (long reply, int html_format);
}
// ============================================================================
// End of Source Code
// ============================================================================
```

Comment: Did you try the command I suggested? It might have been added at a later time (so your servlet will crash) or it might not have been documented (in which case the servlet will run as expected). Anyway, if you drop us a line at www.gwan.com then we will help you further to let you access the feature you need.

Comment: Hello @Gil thanks!, yes i did try, but the Gwan Class does not containt that Method, i will make a contact through www.gwan.com

Comment: Hello @Gil i sent the email through the www.gwan.com form contact, i hope you can see it

Comment: I did send my request/question through the form at the bottom of this page http://www.gwan.com/about

@Gil, do you think it was ok or i have to use other way?

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your email using a **gmail** address has been responded on May 5th. Check you 'junk' gmail inbox.

Comment: Am so sorry @Gil but there is nothing there, do you think is possible to resend it?

Comment: This mail has been resent per your request to your **gmail** address. Use a company email address if gmail keeps blocking.

Comment: Thanks @Gil i did receive it, i hope we can start a further conversation.